# Is there any Touch event for overlayitem?

Tags: android, overlay

I use onTap event but onTap occur when i get finger from screen. And i want to some event for overlayitem for touching. Did anybody understand me what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Mapview Overlay Manager project](http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/), which uses a `GestureListener` to provide the following touch events:

- onSingleTap(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
- onDoubleTap(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
- onLongPress(MotionEvent, ManagedOverlay, GeoPoint, OverlayItem)
- onZoom(ZoomEvent, ManagedOverlay)
- onScrolled(...)

Up to you whether to adopt the whole library or just use it as a guideline for your own implementation. I imagine it shouldn't be too hard to come up with a generic `onTouchevent` method, if none of the five above suit your needs.